# How to debug "error ASPCONFIG: The path is too long after being fully qualified. "?

Tags: path, aspnet-compiler, fully-qualified-naming

I've got a project that contains a script that runs as part of the build process. In this script there is an AspNetCompiler task that doesn't cause any issues when I run the script locally. The task looks something like this:

```
<AspNetCompiler
      VirtualPath="/CompanyName.SolutionName.ComponentName"
      PhysicalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\SolutionName.ComponentName"
      TargetPath="$(TargetFolder)\Setup\SolutionName.ComponentName"
      Updateable="true"
      Force="true"
      Debug="false"
      Clean="true"
      ToolPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\" >
</AspNetCompiler>
```

When I run it on my build server however I get this error:

```
ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: The path is too long after being fully qualified.  Make sure the full path is less than 260 characters and the directory name is less than 248 characters. [(PhysicalPath)]
```

The path in question is definitely less than 260 characters long. In addition the path is shorter on my build server than it is on my local machine. Right now I'm less concerned with solving the error than I am with diagnosing what the issue actually is. The error message is possibly not related to whatever the problem is based on the evidence. I can't necessarily even discern that the path it is complaining about is even the path that is causing the error. Any ideas?